# Explode the contents of the cell in pandas dataframe into different rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a pandas dataframe in which multiple(3) column contains values corresponding to the next column. I want to split each row into multiple rows accordingly and create a new row per entry. For example, 'source' should become

*source

Time (magazine)

WarnerMedia

WarnerMedia

WarnerMedia

U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission

WarnerMedia

AOL
*

The dataframe is of the format

| ID | source | target | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ["': 'Time (magazine)", "': 'WarnerMedia", "': 'WarnerMedia", "': 'WarnerMedia", "': 'U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission", "': 'WarnerMedia", "': 'AOL"] | ["': 'WarnerMedia", "': 'Time (magazine)", "': 'Time (magazine)", "': 'U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission", "': 'WarnerMedia", "': 'AOL", "': 'WarnerMedia"] | ["': 'owned by", "': 'subsidiary", "': 'owned by", "': 'subsidiary", "': 'subsidiary", "': 'subsidiary", "': 'subsidiary"] |
| 1 | ["': 'Federal Reserve", "': 'Bank of America", "': 'London", "': 'New York (state)"] | ["': 'London", "': 'New York (state)", "': 'Federal Reserve", "': 'Bank of America"] | ["': 'headquarters location", "': 'headquarters location", "': 'headquarters location", "': 'headquarters location"] |

I would require the data to be formatted in the following way :

| ID | source | target | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Time (magazine) | WarnerMedia | owned by |
| 0 | WarnerMedia | Time (magazine) | subsidiary |
| 0 | WarnerMedia | Time (magazine) | owned by |
| 0 | WarnerMedia | U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission | subsidiary |
| 0 | U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission | WarnerMedia | subsidiary |
| 0 | WarnerMedia | AOL | subsidiary |
| 0 | AOL | WarnerMedia | subsidiary |

and so on..

I was using pandas explode function, but I could make it work for only one column, I would like to make it work for multiple columns at the same.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: ignore my previous comment. you can do this, and pandas does enforce that each list be the same length.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a list to [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```py
exploded = df.explode(["source", "target", "type"])
```

To explode multiple columns, each list within each cell must have an identical length to the lists in the other cells in the row.